# Android Studio does not load projects properly anymore

Tags: android

For some reason whenever I open my project in Android studio it looks like this

[image: https://imgur.com/KHv2IZU]

It happened before, I tried to reinstall Android Studio which fixed it for like 1 hour, then the same thing happened again, tried to reinstall android studio one more time and now it just doenst work at all.
.
Thank you very much for any answers

Comment: What part are you talking about? That is how android studio would open up when there are no files open

Comment: @KunalShah I am talking about the history on the left side where you would usually want to see gradle and your project, now I can not access any of my classes or activities because they literaly dont show on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

This is faced by many developers like me after updating to AS3.

Try `Import Project...` and navigate to your project. Select `build.gradle` file.

Be sure to wait for a while, so that android studios can load all your stuff. Sometimes a restart will help.

**Gradle sync success is needed, cause project files will not be indexed if gradle build is not successful.**